# How can I convert an audio (.wav) to satellite image

Tags: audio, fft, wave, satellite, noaa

I need to  create a software can capture sound (from NOAA Satellite with RTL-SDR). The problem is not capture the sound, the problem is how I converted the audio or waves into an image. I read many things, Fourier Fast Transformed, Hilbert Transform, etc... but I don't know how.

If you can give me an idea it would be fantastic. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Over the past year I have been writing code which makes FFT calls and have amassed 15 pages of notes so the topic is vast however I can boil it down

Open up your WAV file ... parse the 44 byte header and note the given bit depth and endianness attributes ... then read across the payload which is everything after that header ... understand notion of bit depth as well as endianness ... typically a WAV file has a bit depth of 16 bits so each point on the audio curve will be stored across two bytes ... typically WAV file is little endian not big endian ... knowing what that means you take the next two bytes then bit shift one byte to the left (if little endian) then bit OR that pair of bytes into an integer then convert that int which typically varies from 0 to (2^16 - 1) into its floating point equivalent so your audio curve points now vary from -1 to +1 ... do that conversion for each set of bytes which corresponds to each sample of your payload buffer

Once you have the WAV audio curve as a buffer of floats which is called raw audio or PCM audio then perform your FFT api call ... all languages have such libraries ... output of FFT call will be a set of complex numbers ... pay attention to notion of the Nyquist Limit ... this will influence how your make use of output of your FFT call

Now you have a collection of complex numbers ... the index from 0 to N of that collection corresponds to frequency bins ... the size of your PCM buffer will determine how granular your frequency bins are ... lookup this equation ... in general more samples in your PCM buffer you send to the FFT api call will give you finer granularity in the output frequency bins ... essentially this means as you walk across this collection of complex numbers each index will increment the frequency assigned to that index

To visualize this just feed this into a 2D plot where X axis is frequency and Y axis is magnitude ... calculate this magnitude for each complex number using

```
curr_mag = 2.0 * math.Sqrt(curr_real*curr_real+curr_imag*curr_imag) / number_of_samples
```

For simplicity we will *sweep under the carpet* the phase shift information available to you in your complex number buffer

This only scratches the surface of what you need to master to properly render a WAV file into a 2D plot of its frequency domain representation ... there are libraries which perform parts or all of this however now you can appreciate some of the magic involved when the rubber hits the road

A great explanation of trade offs between frequency resolution and number of audio samples fed into your call to an FFT api https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/12407/what-is-the-relation-between-fft-length-and-frequency-resolution

Do yourself a favor and checkout https://www.sonicvisualiser.org/ which is one of many audio workstations which can perform what I described above.  Just hit menu File -> Open -> choose a local WAV file ->  Layer -> Add Spectrogram  ... and it will render the visual representation of the Fourier Transform of your input audio file as such

[image]